How can I do an ECDH key exchange with OpenSSL 3.0
Most of the API that EC_KEY* functions like EC_KEY_get0_public_key have been deprecated in OpenSSL 3.0, so as far as I know there's no way but to use the EVP interface. I want to export the public key to a buffer, calculate a MAC over it and then verify the MAC before using the key for a DH key exchange at the recipient end.
I could get a EVP_PKEY object with the generated EC key but I cannot figure out how to extract the public key (raw bytes) and the group name in a way that I can reconstruct for an ECDH key exchange.
void generateAndExport() {
  /* params have been set */
  EVP_PKEY_CTX *keygen_ctx;
  EC_PKEY *ec_key;
  size_t pubkey_size;

  if (!(keygen_ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(ec_params, NULL)))
    return -1;

  if (!EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(keygen_ctx))
    return -1;

  if (!EVP_PKEY_keygen(keygen_ctx, &ec_key))
    return -1;

  pubkey_size = 0;
  /* Query the buffer size */
  if (!EVP_PKEY_get_octet_string_param(
          ec_key, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PUB_KEY, NULL, 0, &pubkey_size))
    return -1;

  /* Allocate the buffer for the public key */
  if (!(ec_pub = calloc(1, pubkey_size)))
    return -1;

  /* Get the public key */
  if (!EVP_PKEY_get_octet_string_param(ec_key,
                                       OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PUB_KEY, ec_pub,
                                       pubkey_size, &pubkey_size))
    return -1;

  /* calculate a MAC over the public key */

cleanup:
  EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(keygen_ctx);
  EVP_PKEY_free(ec_key);
  return 0;
}


Edit: This seems to be the correct code for doing exactly what I wanted. If anyone would like to know, here is the code I used for recovering the public key and deriving a shared secret:
void deriveSharedSecret(EVP_PKEY *priv,
                        unsigned char *pkey,
                        size_t pkey_len,
                        unsigned char *group_name,
                        unsigned char **shared_key,
                        size_t *shared_key_len) {
  EVP_PKEY_CTX *derive_ctx = NULL;
  EVP_PKEY *peer_key = NULL;

  CHECK(pkey && (pkey_len > 0));

  CHECK(!(peer_key = EVP_PKEY_new_raw_public_key(
          EVP_PKEY_EC,
          NULL,
          pkey,
          pkey_len)));
  CHECK(derive_ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(priv, NULL));
  CHECK(EVP_PKEY_derive_init(derive_ctx));
  CHECK(EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_group_name(derive_ctx, group_name));
  CHECK(EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer(derive_ctx, peer_key));

  /* Query buffer size for shared secret */
  *shared_key_len = 0;
  CHECK(EVP_PKEY_derive(derive_ctx, NULL, shared_key_len));

  if (!(*shared_key = calloc(1, *shared_key_len)))
    return -1;
  CHECK(EVP_PKEY_derive(derive_ctx, *shared_key, shared_key_len));

  EVP_PKEY_free(peer_key);
  EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(derive_ctx);
  return 0;
}

Also, to get the group name:
unsigned char groupname[MAX_GROUP_NAME_SIZE];
size_t groupname_len;

CHECK(EVP_PKEY_get_octet_string_param(
      ec_key,
      OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_GROUP_NAME,
      groupname,
      0,
      &groupname_len));


You say you can't extract the raw public key, but your code does exactly that (once you fix EC_PKEY to EVP_PKEY and init it); you can also use EVP_PKEY_get1_encoded_public_key. For the group/curve name, use get_utf8_string_param (,OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_GROUP_NAME,). You use an apparently global pointer for location of the pubkey but don't provide its size to any caller; and you need to either save your (generated) privatekey to use when you receive peer publickey, or have this code compute the shared secret using an already received and probably passed-in peer publickey.

I have only used the EC_KEY* functions in the past and not very familiar with the EVP API for ECC. Sorry if this post seems a little desperate, I couldn't find any helpful docs for the same. With a little trial and error I could figure out how to recover the public key from raw bytes as well!
